# MySql %w date format parameter equivalent for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In MySQL to get the day of week we use '%w' format parameter.what is the SQL Server equivalent for doing that? I used 'ddd' but it give me the day name (eg: `Saturday`) not the number.any suggestions?

This is what I've tried:

```
 select FORMAT( SYSDATETIME(), 'ddd', 'fa-IR' )
```

between I am aware of `DATEPART(weekday , GETDATE())` but is lacks `culture` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact replica of MySQL's %w which is always (0=Sunday..6=Saturday)

The easiest way to get 0 for Sunday every time in any SQL Server instance is:

```
datediff(day,-1,[yourdate_value]) % 7
```

What this does is to calculate the number of days since 1899-12-31 (a Sunday), then supply the remainder if divided by 7. A result of 0 will always be Sunday, a result of 6 will always be Saturday.

**NB** T-SQL uses a base date of 1900-01-01 (a Monday) and this base date can be represented by 0 in T-SQL date function such as datediff. So the -1 is one day less that the base date. Instead of -1 you could use any reliable Sunday date, e.g.

```
select datediff(day,'20181104',getdate()) % 7, datediff(day,-1,getdate()) % 7
```

and both columns would always be (0=Sunday..6=Saturday)

---

If you don't use the above, note that in MS SQL Server it is possible to change the day of week that represents zero, this setting is called `datefirst` and you can access the current value of this with:

```
select @@datefirst
```

A datefirst value of 7 in SQL Server = MySQL %w of 0 (Sunday). The initial setting of datefirst is usually established by choice of language, and you can find that language dependent datefirst value using this query:

```
select alias, name, dateformat, datefirst
from sys.syslanguages

              alias                 name          dateformat   datefirst  
 ---- --------------------- -------------------- ------------ ----------- 
   1   English               us_english           mdy                  7  
   2   German                Deutsch              dmy                  1  
   3   French                Français             dmy                  1  
   4   Japanese              日本語                ymd                  7  
   5   Danish                Dansk                dmy                  1  
   6   Spanish               Español              dmy                  1  
   7   Italian               Italiano             dmy                  1  
   8   Dutch                 Nederlands           dmy                  1  
   9   Norwegian             Norsk                dmy                  1  
  10   Portuguese            Português            dmy                  7  
  11   Finnish               Suomi                dmy                  1  
  12   Swedish               Svenska              ymd                  1  
  13   Czech                 čeština              dmy                  1  
  14   Hungarian             magyar               ymd                  1  
  15   Polish                polski               dmy                  1  
  16   Romanian              română               dmy                  1  
  17   Croatian              hrvatski             ymd                  1  
  18   Slovak                slovenčina           dmy                  1  
  19   Slovenian             slovenski            dmy                  1  
  20   Greek                 ελληνικά             dmy                  1  
  21   Bulgarian             български            dmy                  1  
  22   Russian               русский              dmy                  1  
  23   Turkish               Türkçe               dmy                  1  
  24   British English       British              dmy                  1  
  25   Estonian              eesti                dmy                  1  
  26   Latvian               latviešu             ymd                  1  
  27   Lithuanian            lietuvių             ymd                  1  
  28   Brazilian             Português (Brasil)   dmy                  7  
  29   Traditional Chinese   繁體中文             ymd                  7  
  30   Korean                한국어               ymd                  7  
  31   Simplified Chinese    简体中文             ymd                  7  
  32   Arabic                Arabic               dmy                  1  
  33   Thai                  ไทย                  dmy                  7  
  34   Bokmål                norsk (bokmål)       dmy                  1
```

The function `DATEPART(WEEKDAY, YourDateColumn)` responds to the datefirst setting, so IF the datefirst setting is 7, and the datepart value is 0 then it is Sunday. If the datefist setting is 1 then a datepart value of 0 means Monday. [Here is a discussion](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/datefirst-and-datepart-relationship) of this (often confusing) relationship.

You can override these default setting by using:

```
SET DATEFIRST 7 ;  
SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [yourdate_value])
```

and now (0=Sunday..6=Saturday)

Answer (score 1):

You want `DATEPART`:

```
DATEPART(WEEKDAY, YourDateColumn)
```

Note that the return value varies by language, as different languages treat different days as the first day of the week.

Comment: can we get culture specific weekday out of it?

Comment: It is culture specific @BehnamEsmaili , that's what my note in the answer said.

Comment: so how do we specify culture?